# Trying to set finalResult to equal only the array values that contain "chocolate" Clojure

Tags: filter, clojure

```
;;the only function the works is cartesian-product

(def flavorsOne ["chocolate" "Vanilla" "Cherry Ripple"])
(def flavorsTwo ["Lemon" "Butterscotch" "Licorice Ripple"])

;; (def result (map vector flavorsOne flavorsTwo))

    (defn cartesian-product
      ([] '(()))
      ([xs & more]
        (mapcat #(map (partial cons %)
                      (apply cartesian-product more))
                xs)))

(def resultTwo (cartesian-product flavorsOne flavorsTwo))

(def finalResult (filter ["chocolate"] resultTwo))

(filter #(= (:name %) "choccolate") resultTwo)
;; (filter #(= (:name %) "chocolate") flavorsTwo)
;; (println flavorsOne flavorsTwo)
;; (defn IceCreamStore
;;   ())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to understand, but please put more efforts in elaborating your problem next time you post.

```
  (def flavors-1 ["chocolate" "Vanilla" "Cherry Ripple"])
  (def flavors-2 ["Lemon" "Butterscotch" "Licorice Ripple"])

  (->> (for [x flavors-1
             y flavors-2]
         #{x y})
       (filter #(contains? % "chocolate")))
```

I think this is what you'd be looking for.
Your cartesian-product function is overly complicated, and can be succinctly done using for(https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for).

When using 'for', it's better to have the result as sets, because you want to know whether an element (chocolate) is inside or not. If you want the for part to be a function,

```
(defn cartesian-product [x y]
    (for [x flavors-1
          y flavors-2]
      #{x y}))
```

Minor thing. in Clojure, it is typical to use hyphens(-) rather than camel cases.